# How to call CGRectDivide in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to call CGRectDivide and can't figure out the syntax in Swift. The language guide doesn't seem to be any help.

Here's the template:

```
CGRectDivide(rect: CGRect, slice: CMutablePointer<CGRect>, remainder: CMutablePointer<CGRect>, amount: CGFloat, edge: CGRectEdge)
```

My code:

```
var r = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
var mySlice: CGRect
var myRemainder: CGRect
CGRectDivide(rect: CGRect, slice: mySlice<CGRect>, remainder: myRemainder<CGRect>, amount: 44.0, edge: CGRectEdge.MaxYEdge)
```

That gives me an error: "Cannot specialize a non-generic definition"

I'm stumped. So much for Swift being a very readable language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGRectDivide(r, &mySlice, &myRemainder, 44.0, CGRectEdge.MaxYEdge)
```

Comment: Wow. This looked too much like straight C for me to believe, but it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

If you Command-click on a CGRect symbol in your code, you'll be taken to the Swift declaration of struct CGRect. In its first extension you'll find a number of useful methods, including the following:

```
Swift 2:
func divide(atDistance: CGFloat, fromEdge: CGRectEdge) -> (slice: CGRect, remainder: CGRect)

Swift 3:
func divide(_ atDistance: CGFloat, fromEdge: CGRectEdge) -> (slice: CGRect, remainder: CGRect)
```

Which you could use like this:

```
import UIKit

let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let (slice, remainder) = rect.divide(10.0, fromEdge: .MinXEdge) // Swift 3: .minXEdge
print("rect: \(rect)") // prints "rect: (0.0,0.0,100.0,100.0)"
print("slice: \(slice)") // prints "slice: (0.0,0.0,10.0,100.0)"
print("remainder: \(remainder)") // prints "remainder: (10.0,0.0,90.0,100.0)"
```

Comment: The method signature has been changed in recent versions to : public func divide(atDistance: CGFloat, fromEdge: CGRectEdge) -> (slice: CGRect, remainder: CGRect)

Comment: @Lombas Thanks, I've updated the answer for Swift 2 and 3.

Answer (score 6):

Just sample, how you can try to do it:

```
let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
var sliceRect = CGRectZero
var remainderRect = CGRectZero
CGRectDivide (rect, &sliceRect, &remainderRect, 30.0, "CGRectEdge");

print(sliceRect)
print(remainderRect)
```

"CGRectEdge" should be replaced by:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use the new Swift `divide` on `CGRect` instead of `CGRectDivide`:

```
let frames = view.bounds.divide(44.0, fromEdge: .MinYEdge)
let slice = frames.0
let remainder = frames.1
```